# Magento2 : How to set JSON response from custom rest API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, json-response

I'm building a custom rest API endpoint.

This is code which I have written in my custom model class.

```
return [
   ['success' => false,
   'status-title' => 'Refund Failed',]
];
```

Following response I'm getting in Postman while my testing the end point.

```
[
    {
        "success": false,
        "status-title": "Refund Failed"
    }
]
```

I want to JSON response like following example

```
{
        "success": false,
        "status-title": "Refund Failed"
}
```

How Can I set JSON response

```
{
        "success": false,
        "status-title": "Refund Failed"
}
```

Instead of following JSON format

```
[
    {
        "success": false,
        "status-title": "Refund Failed"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify the the return line code to this :

```
return ['success' => false, 'status-title' => 'Refund Failed'];
```

Let me know if it works for you.